# multiselect in angular-ui-select bootstrap- keep items in menu list?

Tags: ui-select, angular-ui-select

Is there a way to keep items in the dropdown list in an angular-mutliselect-ui-select control? 
I want to click an item, so it is added as selected but keep it in the list (if it is clicked again- nothing should happen).

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward hack is to change `$select.removeSelected = true;` to `false` in select.js. A small example is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ue7DMnBfzxePTYJovfrz?p=preview) (see script.js, line: 1244), may be there is a way to do it externally without modifying script.js.

Comment: thank you, the problem is the select control is used in many parts in my application- in some of which I do want the items to be removed, so I can't change this configuration globally